# How to put item on top of the Queue in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, queue

Is it possible to put items on the top of a Queue instead of the bottom?
In same cases I need to re-popoulate the Queue by mantaining the original order after that I've get items.

Comment: Use a double ended queue maybe? `from collections import Deque`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, by definition, putting into a queue is to the end.

You want to use [deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) instead.

Comment: Actually, by definition of a queue, putting and getting happens on different ends.

Comment: @schwobaseggl, of course :) thanks, I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Following on from ***DeepSpace's*** suggestion, here is a simple implementation to put an item at the front (top) of a python queue, using: `appendleft()`

```
from collections import deque

Q=deque([2,1,5,7,4,3])
Q.appendleft(8)
print('{}{}'.format("head: ", Q[0]))
```

**out:**

```
deque([8, 2, 1, 5, 7, 4, 3])
head: 8
```

If you were opposed to using `appendleft()` you could work with list properties and do this:

```
deque([8]+list(Q))
```

**out**:

```
deque([8, 2, 1, 5, 7, 4, 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

The only problem is that `dequeue` doesn't wait for new messages to come on `.pop()`. Push

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
from queue import Queue
q = Queue()
element = 1
q.put(2)
q.put(3)
q.queue.insert(0, element) # Insert element in index 0 (begin).
while not q.empty():
     print(q.get())
```